# Keep getting the user speed network connection in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, networking, ios-animations

I am building out a feature in the app where I have to know the speed connection of the user and draw out a line illustrating the connection speed. I found multiple posts on StackOverflow showing how to get the speed for one time. But the problem is that the user has to download a file to get there speed connection, which will cause the user to waste their internet connection. I was wondering if I can keep track of the user speed connection and draw a line that would illustrate their connectivity, as shown below. Also, I am not sure how I would draw this line and its animation.

[image: c]

Comment: Just like driving speed can only be calculated by driving somewhere, download speed can only be calculated by downloading something.  If your app is a streaming app or ha smother continuous download then you can measure the rate at which that transfer is occurring. If not then you would need to download a file specifically for the purpose of calculating the download speed, which is wasteful, yes.

Comment: it is a VPN app

Comment: Then you can measure the transfer you are already doing.